# selecting appropriate copy-constructor based on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I want to select implementation of a member function (copy constructor) based on a template argument value. I suppose there are two approaches: SFINAE and template partial specialization.

The last one supposedly looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, bool sw>
struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(const B &b);
};

template<typename A>
B<A, false>::B(const B<A, false> &b)
{
    std::cout << "false\n";
}

template<typename A>
B<A, true>::B(const B<A, true> &b)
{
    std::cout << "true\n";
}

int main()
{
}
```

It doesn't compile: `nested name specifier 'B<A, false>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization`.

SFINAE approach fails too:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, bool sw>
struct B
{
    B() {}

    template<typename U = typename std::enable_if<sw, B>::type>
    B(const U &b)
    {
        std::cout << "true\n";
    }

    template<typename U = typename std::enable_if<!sw, B>::type>
    B(const U &b)
    {
        std::cout << "false\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        B<int, true> b;
        auto bc = b; // cout << true
    }
    {
        B<int, false> b;
        auto bc = b; // cout << false
    }
}
```

The compilation error here is `constructor cannot be redeclared` and `no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, B<int, false> >'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration`.

*Is there any way to fix the problems or otherwise select appropriate copy-constructor based on template parameters?*

Comment: You can't do partial specialization on just members of a class (or structure), you need to partially specialize the complete class.

Comment: for the record, one of the problems here is that you can't have a templated copy-constructor (except for the fact that the two signatures are the same in your case, this can be fixed), because an implicitly generated copy-constructor always wins in overload resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename A, bool sw>
struct B
{
    B() = default;

    B(const B& b) : B(b, std::integral_constant<bool, sw>{}) {}

private:
    B(const B& b, std::true_type)
    {
        std::cout << "true\n";
    }

    B(const B& b, std::false_type)
    {
        std::cout << "false\n";
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/711d4ba0be2447dd)

Answer (score 1):

As @Joachim Pileborg said in comment, you can not specialize just one member of a class, you have to specialize the whole class. So your partial specialization will look like this :

```
template<typename A, bool sw>
struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(const B &b);
};

//Specialize when sw is false
template<typename A>
struct B<A, false>
{
     //The constructor in the specialized struct print false
     B(const B &b)
     {
        std::cout << "false\n";
     }
};

//Specialize when sw is true
template<typename A>
struct B<A, true>
{
    //The constructor in the specialized struct print true
    B(const B &b)
    {
        std::cout << "true\n";
    }
};
```

The best solution you can get for SFINAE was given by @Piotr Skotnicki

Comment: *"because you can not redeclare a constructor"* you can redeclare as many times as you want (by changing the signature, like adding a dummy template parameter like `typename = void`), the problem here is that, even if it's fixed, an implicitly generated copy-constructor will always be picked as a better candidate (because it's a non-template)

Comment: You're right and I should have said in my answer that you can not redeclare a constructor with the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a minimal example, but what's wrong with

```
B(const B& b) {
  if(sw) {
    std::cout << "true\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "false\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. But in my case copy constructor uses or doesn't (depends on `sw`) constructor delegation.